# I want to know those numbers who are still not assigned to anyone like (11-19), (201-299), (501-599) and (901-1000)

Tags: sql

I have some ticket Id's between 1 to 500 & 501 to 1000 and out of them I have issued some Id's to other colleagues between (1-10), (20-35), (36-100), (101-200), (300-500) and (600-900).

```
   Table Name:-abc

   issuebybranch     Id_from      Id_to      issuetobranch    type

      delho            1          500            delho          R
      delho            501         1000          delho          R
      delho            1           10             pnb           I
      delho            20          35             amb           I
      delho            36          100            bpl           I
      delho            101         200            gkp           I
      delho            300         500            ccu           I
      delho            600         900            pb            I
```

I want to know those numbers who are still not assigned to anyone like (11-19), (201-299), (501-599) and (901-1000).

Thanks,
Anup Ray

---

Demo DDL (Dudu Markovitz)

```
create table mytable (issuebybranch varchar(100),Id_from int,Id_to int,issuetobranch varchar(100),type char(1));

insert into mytable values ('delho',  1, 500,'delho','R');
insert into mytable values ('delho',501,1000,'delho','R');
insert into mytable values ('delho',  1,  10,'pnb'  ,'I');
insert into mytable values ('delho', 20,  35,'amb'  ,'I');
insert into mytable values ('delho', 36, 100,'bpl'  ,'I');
insert into mytable values ('delho',101, 200,'gkp'  ,'I');
insert into mytable values ('delho',300, 500,'ccu'  ,'I');
insert into mytable values ('delho',600, 900,'pb'   ,'I');
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Using postgres, create a list of 1000 number and check what are already assigned

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/PLWRV83491)**

```
With available as (
    SELECT free_number
    FROM generate_series(1, 1000) AS free_number
    )
SELECT  a.free_number
FROM available a 
LEFT JOIN Table1 t
  ON a.free_number between t."Id_from" and t."Id_to"
 AND t."issuetobranch" <>  'delho'
WHERE t."Id_from" IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for all databases that supports the analytical function LEAD (Tested on Oracle, SQL Server and PostgreSQL).
For Teradata use MIN(...) over (order by ... rows between 1 following and 1 following).

---

1. Ranges are not hard-coded.
   The defined ranges are taken from the table.
2. Ideal performance.
   No values are being generated.
   The existing ranges are being used to create the missing ranges.

---

```
select      id_from
           ,id_to

from       (select      id_to + 1                                 as id_from

                       ,lead (id_from) over 
                        (
                            order by id_from,id_to
                        ) - 1                                     as id_to

                       ,case id_to when -1 then 'Y' else 'N' end  as is_closing_range_rec

            from       (select      id_from                 as id_from
                                   ,case
                                        when type = 'R' 
                                        then id_from - 1 
                                        else id_to 
                                    end                     as id_to

                        from        mytable t

                        union all   

                        select      id_to + 1  as from_id    
                                   ,-1         as to_id

                        from        mytable t 

                        where       type = 'R'
                        ) t
            ) t

 where      id_to >= id_from
        and is_closing_range_rec = 'N'

;
```

---

```
+---------+-------+
| id_from | id_to |
+---------+-------+
| 11      | 19    |
+---------+-------+
| 201     | 299   |
+---------+-------+
| 501     | 599   |
+---------+-------+
| 901     | 1000  |
+---------+-------+
```

Comment: Are you still with us?